# Make posts(images) to google map Business location by API

Tags: php, api, google-maps, maps, posts

**Google map API. Posting publicly on Google products**

I have google business profile and location on google map.
Can I make post images by google API to this company? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Place Photos API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/photos). The Place Photo service, part of the Places API, is a read- only API that allows you to add high quality photographic content to your application. This gives you access to the millions of photos stored in the Places database.

To use, you just have to send Place Photo request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?parameters
```

An example of it is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo
  ?maxwidth=400
  &photo_reference=Aap_uEA7vb0DDYVJWEaX3O-AtYp77AaswQKSGtDaimt3gt7QCNpdjp1BkdM6acJ96xTec3tsV_ZJNL_JP-lqsVxydG3nh739RE_hepOOL05tfJh2_ranjMadb3VoBYFvF0ma6S24qZ6QJUuV6sSRrhCskSBP5C1myCzsebztMfGvm7ij3gZT
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

As you can see, there is a `photo_reference` parameter. This can be found in the response to a [Find Place API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place), [Nearby Search API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby), [Text Search API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text), or [Place Details API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details) web request.

Here is an example of Place Details API web request to get the photo reference of the address `48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia`:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json
  ?fields=photo
  &place_id=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

I use the `photo` in the `fields` parameter to get the address' photo reference: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#Place-photos)

As you can see from the Place Details API response, there are multiple photo references for this address.

To get the photo, we'll just use a photo reference from the Place Details API response, and put it in the `photo_reference` parameter of the Place Photo API request. Here's an example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo
  ?maxwidth=400
&photo_reference=Aap_uEBzMi8oa8zOmZQoAFNNGq1E6wS4GuzFJu-zrNlnB254m8yrHhp9SpE-6U90PaqyLESwpX3avM1wVRKp9enfT_Yo6fl_2GR50nWd_CEJLuBOMZtomgXVdQfL8-7K4rO3hiagtQI44cr4KvQuv-sN9N3FOnIvMqD4W5IZtPgCh1oEZyQI
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: 1) Please stop answering questions that should be closed and 2) Please make sure you understand the question before providing an answer (this one does NOT answer the question at all) and 3) There is no point copy-pasting entire paragraphs of the official documentation into an answer.

Comment: War in Ukraine. Sorry for waiting